# Powershell parameters string or file

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a script that i'd like the user to be able to enter a string or use a file(array) that my script can cycle through.

Can this be done with a parameter?

I'd like to be able to do something like this

```
script.ps1 -file c:\users\joerod\desktop\listofusers.txt
```

or

```
script.ps1 -name "john doe"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, but you will need to pick the default parameterset to use when a positional parameter is used since the type of both parameters is a string e.g.:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="File")]
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="File")]
    [string]
    $File,

    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="Name")]
    [string]
    $Name
)

if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "File") {
    ... handle file case ...
}
else {
    ... must be name case ...
}
```

Where the DefaultParameterSetName is essential is when someone specifies this:

```
myscript.ps1 foo.txt
```

If the default parametersetname specified, PowerShell can't tell which parameterset should be used since both position 0 parameters are the same type `[string]`.  There is no way to disambiguate which parameter to place the argument in.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!  Thanks Keith!