# Powershell - Script that accepts single string param or filelist using Get-Content

Tags: powershell, input

I'm having trouble getting PowerShell to accept a single string param input on the command line OR accept a file as input containing a list of servers.

I've tried working [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374622/powershell-parameters-string-or-file) but I can't get things to work.

I also tried working with `param([switch] $FileList)` but the `IF` statement doesn't reach the `else` block.

What I hope to put together is a script that accepts a single server name passed in on the command line or accepts input from a text file.  I do appreciate any pointers!

-edit, using the below running the script with/without a param returns `Run on single server` and it is the same `if (($FileList -eq $false))`  Using Keith Hill's example, again no matter what I try passing the script the output is always same (the IF block never reaches the `ELSE` block)

-Edit2, the second code example works when passing a single server name to the script, the problem for me is trying to get the `[Switch]` parameter to accept a filename and pass it to the code block with the `foreach` loop.  It errors with the following `Get-EventLog : Invalid value '.\fake.txt' for parameter 'machineName'.` at the ELSE line.

```psh
param([switch] $FileList)
if (($FileList -eq $true)) { "No file list input" }
Else { "Run on single server"}
```

## 2nd code example

```psh
param(
[switch]$FileList,
[string]$server)

if ($FileList -eq $true) {
$list = GC $FileList
foreach ($server in $list){Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName system | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq '6005'} | Select TimeGenerated,Message | Select -first 1}#End foreach
}

Else{
Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName system | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq '6005'} | Select TimeGenerated,Message | Select -first 1
}
```

Comment: which problem do you get using @Keith Hill example ?

Comment: Edited question to provide more detail.  I wasn't able to focus on this until now, apologies for posting an incomplete question.

Comment: A `[switch]` parameter cannot take a value - it's more similar to a boolean. If it's specified in the arguments it becomes `$true`, otherwise its `$false`. If you want an array of servers you need to use `[string[]]$servers` as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're set on using the switch parameter this won't help but if you just want a single parameter that can be a file or server name it will.

```
param (
   [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string]$FileList
)

if (Test-Path $FileList) {
  "File found, do file related commands."
}
Else { "Single server actions." }
```

Comment: Ok this looks great, a simple way to accomplish my goal.  Looking at the `[switch]` option, that would only increase the scripts complexity since it would require the user to enter `-FileList` when the script is run.  Thank you!